# android input multiple keyevent

Tags: android, input, keyevent

I have a question about input key event in Android app.

**I used to input key event with**

> sendKeyDownUpSync() in Instrumentation class.

Input single Key is successful but multiple keys are not working. 
Exactly, I would like to input key event **Shift+Tab** signal to android system. How can I make the input code?